# Devexpress 12.1 MVC GridView Inside Tab Strip Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, devexpress

I'm an intern that has never done any web development just so you know where I'm coming from. I'm currently trying to learn asp.NET MVC 3 using devexpress 12.1 tools. I started with a template that had a devexpress gridview in the content area that is linked up to the Northwind db. It works by itself, but when I create a devexpress tab strip and place the gridview inside the second tab I get the column headings, but no data is displayed. When I click on a column heading to sort the data shows up. I'm wanting the gridview to load after I click the tab and not when the page loads. Maybe my callbacks are the problem. My tab strip is using an ajax callback and the gridview is as well for the paging. I have added the model to the TabControlPartial page and passed in the model in the controller for the TabControlPartial action. I've tried looking at the demos at mvc.devexpress.com, but there is nothing that puts the two together. I don't 100% understand passing the model into the view I guess. I know this is simple, but I don't know what to do. Thanks for your help.

---

Controller (this may be my issue):

```
public ActionResult LookUp()
{
    return View(NorthwindDataProvider.GetCustomers());
}

public ActionResult _TabControlPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_TabControlPartial", NorthwindDataProvider.GetCustomers());
}

public ActionResult _GridViewPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", NorthwindDataProvider.GetCustomers());
}
```

---

LookUp View (Index):

```
@model System.Collections.IEnumerable

@Html.Partial("_TabControlPartial", Model)
```

---

Tab Partial:

```
@model System.Collections.IEnumerable

@Html.DevExpress().PageControl(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "TabControl";
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Customers", Action =
        "_TabControlPartial" };

    settings.TabPages.Add(
        tabOne =>
        {
            tabOne.Name = "TabOne";
            tabOne.Text = "Start";
            tabOne.SetContent(() =>
            {
                ViewContext.Writer.Write("Start");
            });
        });
    settings.TabPages.Add(
        tabTwo =>
        {
            tabTwo.Name = "TabTwo";
            tabTwo.Text = "Customer List";
            tabTwo.SetContent(() =>
            {
                 Html.RenderPartial("_GridViewPartial", Model);
            });
        });
}).GetHtml()
```

GridView Partial:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "GridView";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Customers", Action = 
          "_GridViewPartial" };

    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
    settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = 15;
    settings.ControlStyle.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
    settings.ControlStyle.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
    settings.ControlStyle.BorderBottom.BorderWidth =   
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(1);

//Configure grid's columns in accordance with data model fields
    settings.Columns.Add("ContactName");
    settings.Columns.Add("Address");
    settings.Columns.Add("City");
    settings.Columns.Add("PostalCode");
    settings.Columns.Add("Phone");
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Can you show us your `_GridViewPartial`?

Comment: Oops. Thanks @ScottieMc. I meant to have that in original post. Added now.

Comment: Hopefully this will point you in the right direction. Check out the [CallbackPanel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2927.aspx) control and the client side [TabStrip events](http://mvc.devexpress.com/TabControl/ClientSideAPI). You should be ablel to use the `ActiveTabChanged` client side event to force the CallbackPanel to render.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the data in the GridView when the tab is opened. When you open the page, the data for the GridView needs to be loaded in the Model that is returned. right now you load the page (in LookUp), but you aren't pushing the data for the grid. whenever any callback occurs, only at that point is the data getting pulled from the database and returned to the screen (notice you only return data in the Callback methods _TabControlPartial and _GridViewPartial). When you sort a column, or filter, etc, then the callback is fired and the data is returned from the server.

The code you have looks correct, but somewhere in the process the Model is losing it's value. the best option is to put a breakpoint in the tab control, the Grid Binding, and the controller and make sure the data you expect is in place when it's bound.

You could "cheat" by putting in a callback when the tab is activated such as:

```
@Html.DevExpress().PageControl(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "TabControl";
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Init = "TabControl_Init";
    ...
}).GetHtml()
```

and in JavaScript have:

```
function TabControl_Init(s, e) {
    GridView.PerformCallback();
}
```

this way, after the tabs are initialized, the GridView will run a callback, and grab the data correctly. But it would be better to figure out why the data isn't being sent down in the first place by stepping through the code.